# AngularJs Route doesn't work after Node reinstall

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I'm an AngularJS Developer and this issue happend to me a couple of times.
My Routing worked Fine till yesterday.I had problem with my node so I did what every body would do if you can't fix it go back to zero. Today I tried out my application and it worked well but my routing doesn't work I haven't changed any thing to the code so where could this problem com From?

Thank you for Helping.

Comment: what routing? both node and angular have routing so you need to be more specific. Use version control to avoid ever having to `go back to zero`

Comment: I normaly use version control but you know end of the year and tons of work. The Angular Routing I use grunt to test my webapp

Comment: Yeaaaaa... if you could post any errors, that would be great.

Comment: @Phix that's the thing i dont have any the console log is empty.

Comment: So, how is one supposed to debug an issue without any errors?  I assume you're working with `ng-route`? Bower? Is this an express issue?  Need more info.

Comment: Yes ng-route bower and grunt I dont use express i just test it localy. I'm really sorry that i cant tell you more. If I could i would

Comment: you haven't even provided example of symptoms or troubleshooting steps you've tried